# How to show Microsoft teams shifts to custom calendar in SharePoint using react js

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, calendar, microsoft-teams, web-parts

I need some help in getting Microsoft Teams Shifts and show them in Custom Calendar in SharePoint using ReactJs. I have searched a lot but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to integrate Microsoft Teams Shifts and Custom Calendar in SharePoint.

Microsoft will always focus on customer’s feedback and experience, some new features would be added to the services based on customers' feedback in the future, we also recommend you give your new idea in Teams UserVoice [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) if this needs to be consider as a future request.